# How to ensure ordered processing of children in ChildAdded event listener?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I need to make sure that children added to a DatabaseReference are processed in order. It is possible that the branch where the children are being added, gets multiple children added to it once. When the children are added at small intervals, everything works fine.

To tackle this, I've already implemented an index based solution. I add a field "index" in each child and ensure on Cloud Functions (the code that adds these children) that this index is incremental for all children. I then do the following to implement it:

```
MyDatabaseReference.OrderByChild("index").ChildAdded += HandleTheChild;
```

Most of the time this works, but there are still times when I get bugs similar to when I faced bugs due to wrong ordering of the children. My hypothesis is that the HandleTheChild function is triggered in order always, but it is possible that a child starts to be handled before the previous child is completely processed by the HandleTheChild function. This is creating some race conditions in their parallel execution. I want that each child be processed only after all previous children have been processed in the order they are arriving. Is my hypothesis wrong? If not, should I go forward with an implementation of the solution of the Producer-consumer problem on my Unity client?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code for HandleTheChild.  Also, please explain how you are observing that a child starts to be handled before the previous child is completely processed by the HandleTheChild function.

Comment: The purpose of the question is not to debug my code. Rather I want to know if my hypothesis is correct. I'm not sure what was the correct way to ask the question, so I included my use case and the problem I'm facing. I have not made the observation yet because the bug appears very rarely and I'm still making hypothesis to identify my next step. I want to go to the observation and debugging part only when I'm sure this is a possible problem.

Comment: I'm trying to examine the possibility that your code is doing something other than what you expect.  Everything is a possible source of error, and I'm not sure how to think about it with understanding all the moving parts.  I would never expect there to be any parallelism in the invocations of the callback.  That's not the way any of the other client platforms work.

Comment: I'm just looking for this answer. Is parallelism possible in the invocations of the callback? Thanks for making it concise for me. Unity+Firebase have given a lot of trouble in thread handling due to Unity forcing everything to run on its main thread and Firebase disobeying. Should this question be asked somewhere else?

Comment: If you think the Firebase SDK is not working the way it should, then file a bug with Firebase support. Otherwise, without showing code, there's not much Stack Overflow can do to help.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Don't do this *I've already implemented an index based solution*. If there's any possibility of a race condition or when you need guaranteed order of written data use Firebase transactions to write the data. From the docs *When working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction operation.*

Comment: You do not understand my question. There's no concurrent modification on the database. Multiple children of a database branch being processed parallely on the client is possibly the problem which I'm asking here.

Comment: uh. Hmm. *being processed parallely* means that the app could be working on the same data 'parallely' which could be *concurrent modification*. Regardless of that, it seems the question is not clear enough for us to understand the issue. Perhaps some code would help? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

When you first attach a listener to `ChildAdded` it fires for all children, in the order that you request them.

After that, the `ChildAdded` listener fires when a child is added to the database. In this case, the child may be inserted somewhere in the middle of the data (e.g. if its `index` is lower than existing indexes. The `ChildAdded` listener will fire and has a [`PreviousChildName` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/child-changed-event-args.html#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_child_changed_event_args_1af625f907b296fdbeeecc85068337540b) for this case. This contains the key/id/name of the number after which the new child was added.

My guess is that you're not using `PreviousChildName`, but (as Doug commented) it's hard to be certain without seeing that code.

Comment: I've mentioned in my question that I'm ensuring that the children added have incrementing index only. I'm doing this by saving the index on a separate branch to maintain the state. Tested this as well by checking the timestamps when they were added and it works as expected.

Comment: Clearly what you've ensured isn't working though. Instead of describing in words what you've done, please make sure your question includes the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it is quite useful). Without those, we can't help efficiently (nor effectively as my attempted answer shows).